# Accessing the build revision number in Powershell script during TFS build

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I can get the build number from IBuildDetail.BuildNumber but this is taken from the build definition and there fore might not include the revision number $(Rev:.r) or it might not be at the end.

So I would like to get this number without having to parse it from the build number.  Is this property available any where during the build?

Comment: You can't get just "the revision number" without parsing -- it is not stored as a separate field somewhere.  The `$(Rev:.r)` portion instructs TFS to come up with the first number that makes the build number unique (and, in that specific example, put a dot in front of it).  Only the final build number is available, as KMoraz's answer suggests.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, was hoping not to rely on something that can be externally changed.  But if it can not be done, then so be it :)

Comment: revision number may only be added at the end of the BuildNumber

Answer (score 6):

you can use following powershell script to parse Build number

```
[String]$myrev = $Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
$result = $myrev.Substring($myrev.LastIndexOf('.') + 1)
Write-Host $result
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [build variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/scripts/variables).

From PowerShell use `$Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER` if you’re using TFS 2015.

See MSDN: [**Use a PowerShell script to customize your build process**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/scripts/index)

For previous versions: [**Team Foundation Build environment variables**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448(v=vs.120).aspx)